# Error:Module "myModule" production: java.lang.StackOverflowError in IntellijIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stack-overflow

Does anybody know how to fix this ? When I try to run any tests it just shows up. Was reinstalling idea, adding heap space, restarting computer. Nothing helped.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log and build.log ("Help | Show Log in...") if "invalidate cache" doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try invalidate caches 
**Click File -> Invalidate caches**

This may help